# Qt XQuery Performance

Tags: xml, qt, xquery

I am considering using Qt for developing a new XML-based application that makes heavy use of XQuery. I am especially excited about the way QtXmlPatterns apparently lets you query any data with an appropriate model as if it were XML. I've used XML databases and other query engines in the past (mainly Saxon and BaseX) and am wondering about the performance of XQuery under Qt. I've seen some older evidence that it's a little slow, but that's probably out of date by now.

Does anyone have any (recent) benchmarks comparing Qt XQuery to other XQuery engines. What about anecdotal evidence? Does the Qt XQuery engine allow the use of indexes or other ways to speed up queries through preprocessing (I couldn't find any)?

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider Zorba XQuery Processor?

Comment: I've looked at and am familiar with Sedna, Berkley DB XML, eXtend and a couple others. I mainly wanted to see what experience people had with Qt's capabilities in specific since there are some obvious benefits to using a processesor that's tightly integrated into your main environment.